# Comparing paths

Tags: javascript, path, location, pathname

In my function user inputs a path like `'./images/profile'` and i need to check whether the current path of the page is same as the path he passed.
I. e. check whether `path == location.pathname`.

if `location.pathname` is `/scripts` and the path entered `./../parent/scripts` where parent is parent directory of scripts, the comparison should return `true` and it should return `false` if path entered is `./../parent/images` etc.
So is there any method in JS to comapre two paths?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var p = currentpath + inputpath;
var frags = p.split("/");
for (var i=0; i<frags.length; i++) {
    if (i>0 && frags[i] == "..") {
        frags.splice(i-1, 2);
        i -= 2;
    } else if (!frags[i] && frags[i][0] == ".") { // removes also three or more dots
        frags.splice(i, 1);
        i--;
    }
}
return frags.join("/") == suggestedpath;
```

should do the task. Maybe a regexp would be shorter, but it doesn't allow navigation in Arrays :-)

Answer (score 1):

There's no built-in way to compare or resolve paths. You'll have to resort to parsing the strings, or some kind of hack like loading the relative path in a hidden iframe and checking if its `location.href` is equal to the current window's `location.href`... not that I'm advocating that approach.

Answer (score -1):

```
function comparePath(path1, path2) {
  var path1Dir = path1.substring(path1.lastIndexOf('/'));
  var path2Dir = path2.substring(path2.lastIndexOf('/'));
  return path1Dir == path2Dir;
}
```

You can get the result by calling: `comparePath(path, location.pathname);`

Comment: This will give a false positive when comparing any paths that end in a commonly-named subdirectory, like `foo/bar` and `fizz/bar`.